# Не могу установить windows 11 вместо ubuntu 22.04

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu

Acer aspire 7 A715-42G-R6VJ
У меня стоит ubuntu 22.04 и теперь я хочу поставить windows 11. я подготовил флешку но при включении зажимая клавиши fn + f9 или 12 ничего не происходит. при нажатии на клавишу esc выходит варианты между просто ubuntu и продвинутый ubuntu и ничего другого. образы windows скачивал с официального сайта и через torrent, устанавливал его через rufus, но ничего не получилось

Comment: попробуй в биосе поменять приоритет загрузки

Comment: надо чтобы флешка была UEFI